# Are the lockdown methods implemented for COVID-19 unprecedented?

Tags: medical-science, covid-19, public-health, epidemiology

The [The Great Barrington Declaration](https://gbdeclaration.org/) and it's [FAQ](https://gbdeclaration.org/frequently-asked-questions/) make several claims that fly in the face of our approach to this pandemic. The declaration, when read in it's entirety, states lockdowns are not a part of focused protection, and focused protection has been the standard approach for past epidemics, which *explicitly* implies the lockdown methods used in response to COVID-19 are unprecedented.

Some notable quotes that emphasize the claim made by the declaration (emphasis mine):

> Isn’t Focused Protection too risky an experiment?
>
> No. Focused protection is based on the risk-based strategies outlined
> in the [many pandemic preparedness plans](https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/en/seasonal-influenza/preparedness/influenza-pandemic-preparedness-plans) that different countries had
> developed during the past decades. Surprisingly, **except for Sweden,
> all countries threw their pandemic plans out the window when this
> pandemic started**.
>
> How were prior pandemics dealt with?
>
> **The focused protection strategy** proposed by the Great Barrington
> declaration **is indeed the standard way that societies have dealt with
> prior epidemics**. Letting people who face very little risk from viral
> infection (but would suffer from the lockdowns) live their lives
> normally while taking precautions when they interact with more
> vulnerable people makes intuitive sense – they are harmed by the
> lockdowns and lifting the restrictions helps them.  At the same time,
> better focused protection for the vulnerable is a moral necessity.
>  Over time, population immunity will build up among the non-vulnerable
> until the vulnerable will no longer be at high risk of COVID-19 when
> engaging in normal activities.

To define lockdown, I'll again reference the FAQ:

> How do you define lockdowns?
>
> Lockdowns consist of a variety of measures, such as schools and
> universities that are closed for in-person teaching, hybrid schools,
> closed or partially closed restaurants and other businesses,
> restrictions on sports and cultural events, extraordinary travel
> restrictions, work-from-home orders, cancelled medical and dental
> visits, curfews, quarantine regulations, etc.

This quote drives home the clear statement that lockdowns are not any part of focused protection described by the document:

> Those who are not vulnerable should immediately be allowed to resume
> life as normal. Simple hygiene measures, such as hand washing and
> staying home when sick should be practiced by everyone to reduce the
> herd immunity threshold. Schools and universities should be open for
> in-person teaching. Extracurricular activities, such as sports, should
> be resumed. Young low-risk adults should work normally, rather than
> from home. Restaurants and other businesses should open. Arts, music,
> sport and other cultural activities should resume. People who are more
> at risk may participate if they wish, while society as a whole enjoys
> the protection conferred upon the vulnerable by those who have built
> up herd immunity.

To further clarify, **focused protection** *as described by the declaration* **excludes lockdowns as described above**, basically stating the cost is higher than the cost of increased infection (without any quantification, not the claim here though). To implement a lockdown is therefore not a part of focused protection in this context. With that in mind, the declaration as a whole clearly claims there is no precedent for the lockdown methods used this year. Is this claim true?

Original title: Is the outlined method of managing COVID-19 in The Great Barrington Declaration the "standard" approach?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116254/discussion-on-question-by-tcooper-are-the-lockdown-methods-implemented-for-covid).